# Is this MySQL transposition group by query optimizable?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, pivot-table, transpose, query-performance

my_table holds 290M rows and I wish to optimize the following query

```
select
  col1,
  col2,
  group_concat(distinct case when col3=1 then col4 end) c1,
  group_concat(distinct case when col3=2 then col4 end) c2,
  ...
  group_concat(distinct case when col3=70 then col4 end) c70
from my_table
group by col1,col2
order by null
```

I already tried running smaller queries like this one but the whole thing is worse

```
select
  col1,
  col2,
  group_concat(distinct case when col3=1 then col4 end) c1
from my_table
group by col1,col2
order by null
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one, because you are querying against just a single table.  I can suggest the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON my_table (col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

MySQL *might* choose to use this index, on the grounds that for every `(col1, col2)` group it can do an index scan to find each value of `col3`, and then concatenate together the distinct values of `col4`.

Comment: Will a `explain` show an index scan ? Can a do it on a sample (the last index I created took 5 hours)?

Comment: Yes, you may try using a smaller sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

(Please use real column names; often there are useful clues there.)

*Maybe* this will be faster...

First, let's see how fast it is to do all the `GROUP_CONCATs` at once:

```
SELECT col3,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col4) AS list
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY col3;
```

That will take a full table scan (290M rows), but it can be sped up with

```
INDEX(col3, col4)  -- in this order
```

which is 'covering'.

However, since you have `col1` and `col2` muddying the works, let's change to

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col4) AS list
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY col1, col3, col3;
```

and

```
INDEX(col1, col2, col3, col4)   -- in this order
```

At that point, you have all the data but need to "pivot" it.  (See the `[pivot]` tag.)